# Date And Time Issues With Azure Functions And CosmosDb

Tags: c#, azure, datetime, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I used to take a "Snap Shot" of our system from a app (client) in our UK office. The snapShot was identified by a time mark from the date and time of the snapshot. In CosmosDb the time stamp looked like this.

```
"timeMark": "2018-05-11T15:14:51"
```

This was the time in the UK using `DateTime.Now` and was the actual time in the UK that the snapShot was taken.
I thought that it would be a good idea to put the snapshot client in to a  Azure  Function App and fire it automatically every 5 mins. This is working well except that the time mark was an hour wrong. I wanted the timemark on CosmosDb to be readable as the actual time in the Uk. I used this code to alter the timemark on the Azure function:

```
public static DateTime UkTime(DateTime t)
{
    TimeZoneInfo ukTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
    DateTime utcDate = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime ukTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDate, ukTimeZone);
    return ukTime;
}
```

The timemark now looks like this on CosmosDb

```
"timeMark": "2018-09-28T05:00:04+00:00"
```

Which reads as the correct time it was taken in UK (Summer Time). Now when I read the timeback its an hour forward of what it should be.

Totally confused as best way to approach this. 
Basically UK at the moment is GMT+ 01 hour ahead of GMT Sep in October it will revert back to GMT + 00  hour. I want to be able to read the "raw" document on CosmosDb as the correct time in the UK that the snapShot was taken and read it back in to the an app as such. Seems unnecessarily complex!

Comment: Azure (and I suppose all other cloud providers do the same) *always* uses UTC/GMT independent of the location of the datacenter you use

Answer (score 1):

I set the function to reside in UK South. I set WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE in the Azure portal to GMT Standard Time and instead of using DateTime.Now I used DateTimeOffSet.

```
 DateTime uk = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second, 0);
 DateTimeOffset uk1 = new DateTimeOffset(uk);
```

I now get the correct timeMark in CosmosDb

```
 "timeMark": "2018-09-28T10:36:02+01:00"
```

When I read back from CosmosDb the timeMark is correct.